# PHP Search Engine loop fail

Tags: php, loops, search-engine

I need a little help with my code here. So far, when I go to the page, whole view is seen. When I set search and POST it, it works too. But when I add --> 2 or more <-- keywords, i get an error. So the problem is in the forearch loop else construction.

In that case I get this error:

query fout You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname' at line 6

I tried many ways of constructing, but somehow doesnt seem to work.

My code is below:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $search);
    $customerlistquery = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN company
    ON customer.compid=company.compid
    WHERE 
    ";

    foreach ($terms as $each) 
    {
        $i++;

        if ($i == 1)
        {
            $customerlistquery .= "concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%' ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname";
        }
        else
        {
            $customerlistquery .= "OR concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%' ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname";
        }
    }
}
else
{
$customerlistquery = "  
        SELECT *
        FROM customer
        LEFT JOIN company
        ON customer.compid=company.compid
        ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname
        ";
}
```

And just one last more question. Why is PHP whining about undefined variable: **i**?

```
Notice: Undefined variable: i in ...
```

Is this a standard message at every "throwaway variable"?

Comment: **$i** is undefined the first time round, you need to initialize it for example `$i = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@newfurniturey is right, the first time you use `$i`, is here: `$i++;` Basically, your adding `1` to something that doesn't exist: `$i` hasn't been declared, so there's no value to which you can add 1.

Yes, you *could* just turn the notices off, just hiding them. Your logs, however will get cluttered very quickly. It's therefore good practice to write your code in such a way so that it runs under `E_STRICT | E_ALL` settings without any warnings or notices.

After you've addressed this issue, I can tell you now that you'll see SQL syntax errors all over the place, too:

```
foreach ($terms as $i => $each) 
{//use the index in a foreach loop, that's the easiest solution
    if ($i === 0)
    {
        $customerlistquery .= "concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%' ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname";
    }
    else
    {
        $customerlistquery .= "OR concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%' ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname";
    }
}
```

Each bit of query you concatenate ends in an ORDER BY clause. SQL won't accept query's that look like

```
SELECT foo FROM db.bar WHERE x LIKE '%Y%' ORDER BY x,z OR x LIKE '%x%' ORDER BY x,z
```

So I'd suggest you concat the `ORDER BY` clause *after* the loop:

```
foreach ($terms as $i => $each) 
{//use the index in a foreach loop, that's the easiest solution
    if ($i === 0)
    {
        $customerlistquery .= "concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%'";
    }
    else
    {
        $customerlistquery .= "OR concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%'";
    }
}
$customerlistquery .= ' ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname';
```

Once you get this query to run, don't be surprised if its *dead slow*: The top 3 things to slow query's right down are:

1. Bad indexing
2. overuse of `LIKE` with wildcards
3. Lots of `OR` clauses

If your query has 2 of these three characteristics, there's a 99% chance that SQL will perform a full table scan and write a temp table to disk. Far from ideal, then.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your SQL error - you're looping through a list of terms to build a `WHERE` clause. However, in each iteration, the query you append also contains an `ORDER BY` clause. With a single term, this will work fine. 2+ terms and you have invalid SQL.

Try updating your loop to only append `WHERE`-clause items and add the `ORDER BY` after:

```
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    if ($i++ > 0) $customerlistquery .= ' OR ';
    $customerlistquery .= "concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname) LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
$customerlistquery .= " ORDER BY custsurname, custforename, custmidname";
```

I've also changed your loop a little to accomplish the same task but without the duplicate code.

To address the issue regarding your `undefined variable` warnings, this occurs when you try to use the variable without declaring it. In the case if `$i`, you never define it (such as `$i = 0;`), but you use `$i++` - which is what would cause the warning.

You can turn these notices off using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

However, you actually use the variable in the code; instead, add `$i = 0;` before you enter the `foreach` loop to fix the actual problem.